# move flowLayoutPanel content via two buttons from right to left

Tags: vb.net

I have flowLayoutPanel have contents (controls ) and two button , one at the right and another to the left
the design in [image](http://dc696.4shared.com/img/hboWCukYba/s7/14e2a835170/layoutPanel?async&rand=0.19320773147046566)

I want to make layout panel scroll her content with right button to right and the left button to left , how can I do this please ?

i using this code to do this from top to buttom , but i need it right and left

the code is

```
 Dim ypos As Integer
```

the code in the top button is

```
If ypos > flowLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum - 451 Then
ypos = flowLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum - 450

Else
ypos += 450
flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(0, ypos)
End If
```

and buttom button 
     If ypos < 1 Then
     ypos = 0

```
 Else
 ypos -= 450
 flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(0, ypos)
 End If
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase and decrease the value of `HorizontalScroll.Value` in the respective left and right button click events.

```
 ''' <summary>
    ''' determine the approx total width of all inner controls
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Function approxInnerWidth() As Integer
        Dim returnVal As Integer
        For Each ctl As Control In ControlsFlowLayoutPanel.Controls
            returnVal += ctl.Width
        Next
        Return returnVal
    End Function

    Private Sub LeftButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LeftButton.Click

        'scroll in 1/20th increments
        Dim scrollVal = approxInnerWidth() \ 20

        If ControlsFlowLayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value > scrollVal Then
            ControlsFlowLayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value = ControlsFlowLayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value - scrollVal
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub RightButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RightButton.Click

        'scroll in 1/20th increments
        Dim scrollVal = approxInnerWidth() \ 20

        ControlsFlowLayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value = ControlsFlowLayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value + scrollVal

    End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think so, but I'll have a play around and update back here if a good solution presents itself.

Comment: Quite a few suggestions elsewhere to put your flowlayoutpanel INTO another panel. Leave autostroll on and reduce the height of the outer panel to prevent the scrollbar from appearing.